# White Screen appears at launch when a sound file played SKAction

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying to get a background sound file to play in the GameScene.swift file. But whenever I do and call the run.SKAction, the screen turns white and I hear a lot of static until it crashes. When I comment out the run.SKAction the game starts normally. Ive tried changing the formats of the file to WAV, MP3, AAC, CAF. But the same thing happens.  I checked to see if I mispelled anything but I did not.

It gives me a message saying: "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue"

IMPORTANT NOTE: the "waitForCompletion is set to TRUE it seems to work fine with a little static at the beginning of the soundtrack then it plays normally. but when "waitForCompletion" is set to FALSE I get the white screen. I Also Sometimes get a message saying:

SKAction: Error loading sound resource: "Entry.m4a"

I tried several different soundtrack files but it always happens.

Here is the beginning of the GameScene():

```
class GameScene: SKScene {


var SpaceShip2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"IntroSpaceShip")


var GameSceneSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("BackgroundSound.wav", waitForCompletion: false) 


}
```

Here is the function I used to call the sound:

```
func playsound(soundVariable: SKAction){

    run(SKAction.repeatForever(soundVariable))
}
```

And here is when I call it:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    playsound(soundVariable: GameSceneSound)
}
```

Can someone please help me!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `waitForCompletion` is set to false, the action is considered to be have been completed immediately when run. Since this is a `repeatForever` action, the next repetition of the action runs before the the first action of playing the sound has completed. The 2nd repetition runs, immediately causing the 3rd repetition, which causes the 4th one, etc. Eventually you fill up too much memory with all the SKActions and the app is terminated by iOS.

I would suggest having `waitForCompletion` set to `true`. That way the 2nd repetition of the action won't start until the 1st action has completed playing the sound.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh! I see.  Thank you for the response. I found a way to do it by using AVFoundation. Do you recommend using this for the background music in spritekit or is SKAction better ?

Comment: @Alex Merlin you're welcome! I would rather suggest AVFoundation for background music. SKAction sound playing was buggy on iOS 9, don't know if it has been fixed since then.